# Get File name from a dash delimited string in python lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a bunch of file name like this in s3

```
1623130500-1623130500-Photo-verified-20210631-0-22.csv.gz
1623130500-1623130500-Add-to-cart-20210631-0-4.csv.gz
```

with lambda python code can I separate only **Photo-verified / Add-to-cart** from the above?

I need a solution which give me file name on runtime from above kind of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking how to extract either `Photo-verified` or `Add-to-cart` from the above strings.

You can **split on `-`** and then extract the portion you want. Basically, you don't want the first two parts or the last 3 parts, so use:

```
filename.split('-')[2:-3]
```

That will return a list with:

```
['Photo', 'verified']
```

You could then `join()` them together using:

```
'-'.join(filename.split('-')[2:-3])
```

This would give:

```
Photo-verified
```

On the second string, it would give:

```
Add-to-cart
```